# I want to appeal deletion of a specific question

Tags: discussion

I want to appeal the action taken by moderator. [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/255627/what-are-characteristics-of-secure-totp-2fa-authenticator) was deleted, but I think it was a legit & normal question, and doesn't deserve to be deleted. The moderator has also deleted the answer too. I don't know if that was the reason, but surprisingly to me, he says [in a comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/255627/what-are-characteristics-of-secure-totp-2fa-authenticator#comment526244_255628) that *"..The TOTP does not need to be secure on the device..."* . I am astonished to hear that from a person in a security-field . So, that means all Top-class security apps (like 1Password, LastPass, WinAuth, and name any serious app, which prove to work oppositely) are unaware/underqualified in security field, in contrary to the moderator, at such level that opposite thoughts/questions are even erased from site.
So, I think the opinion that moderator shared (as seen in comment) in the subject is not correct, and moreover, the action to delete the question.
I've tried to communicate with him and ask few questions, related to in-details of security apps, but I only repeatedly hear that "I made a rant" (which **I absolutely refuse and never admitted**, oppositely, I said that was ironic when I called my post a "rant").

Of course, I don't wish to argue with moderator, but I just think the question and answer have not been so bad, that deserved such straightforward deletion, and I wish the question & answer was recovered back. I want another moderator take a look and objectively judge and tell, if that Q/A doesn't have a right to be on SE, and deserved such a targeted deletion, and also mention which action of moderator was mistake - to leave topic open (even he edited the question & answer initially and allowed it to exist) or his later decision to delete it because of a specific comment made later (does a single comment decides the fate of the Q&A itself?)

Comment: I've had a good look, and to be honest, it doesn't look like a good faith question. As @schroeder says in his answer below, you were called out on it being a rant, and admitted it. That is not acceptable behaviour here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Is not this strange that I hear it 5th times that and 5th times I repeat that I've not admitted that it was rant. In opposite, I've refused it to be a rant (in a ironic manner). I am so surprised, after I've been explaining that much clear, and so many times, and moreover giving the question "where there is seen an opinion or rant or incorrect question" , repeatedly no one of you answers that, instead, I repeatedly read that "i made a rant". It's a bit unfortunate that here I see no distinction between argumented critisizm and a rant. You can call anything a rant, but

Comment: as I've asked multiple time to @schroeder (but still hasn't responded) can you please answer me: (A) **In my question**, can you cite where I make a rant ? (B) **In my answer**, can you cite where I posted a rant or any waste private opinion without arguments or facts (mentioning & backing up my opinions based on top prominent security apps) ? (C) What is the reason that question & answer does not have a right to be left as open on SE, or which sentence needs to be changed exactly? I am really interested in answers. thanks.

Comment: Soo... I see what you wrote under Schroeder's answer below, so I'm a little puzzled as to your denial. The question itself doesn't seem to be a well formed, good-faith question. You seem to have 2 questions (also a reason for closure) that exist solely to publish your opinion as answer. Not suitable here.

Comment: Rory's comments also fully encompass my own feeling after review.

Comment: @RoryAlsop ok, end of story. I don't see any point to continue arguing.  Still getting emphasized that " i did rant" (while I really refuse that and stated as ironical ).  After asking that many times, I get no answers to my (1)(2)(3) sub-questions asked here. Ok, I am giving up fully.

Comment: Whenever a "question" includes phrases like "I think there should", it's very likely a rant. Questions don't make statements about what *ought* to be.

Comment: @MechMK1 Instead of emphasizing the Quesiton, you are again just running after a specific phrase. Is mentioning "I think" a reason for deletion (not just closing)? Ok, I  adjusted that, now isn't that ok? instead of helping to just edit that question to fit SE, no-one helped a tiny bit to undelete that Q&A, and avoiding to answer my above concerns. 

and if you were right, then would have done justice and deleted (not just closed) all these questions: https://data.stackexchange.com/security/query/1507004/?txt=i+think . Otherwise, rant (? maybe discrimination?) is what I am getting here.

Comment: @T.Todua The problem isn't "I think", the problem is "there should". As every single person here has explained, your question doesn't seek knowledge - your "question" explains what you believe the status quo *should be*.

Comment: @MechMK1 where I asked that `there should be smth` (other than a question "shouldnt' there be ..?" which is quite normal from an OP to **ask**). One thing is obvious - not only none of you could answer to my `(A)(B)(C)` regards, but moreover you added a new (let's call it `D`) proof that your actions are not correct - here the undeleted questions with "there should be" - https://data.stackexchange.com/security/query/1507004/?txt=should+be . So, delete (don't close, but delete) them, after that answer (A,B,C), to be somehow near to correctness. Otherwise, as now proved, targeted discrimination.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, it's quite simple: you're not asking a question. You want to tell us your feelings on TOTP apps without a lock. That's for a blog, reddit, etc. You have not asked a legitimate question.

Two people called your posts a rant, and *you confirmed it*. You later say that you were joking, but your confirming comment was not in humor; you were explaining why you felt justified in ranting.

The problem, as I explained, was not the content of your opinion on the matter. Rather, that this is not the place to air your opinions.

Comment: 1) Give a proof (cite from the question) where the question is seen to be "sharing a feeling" ? 
2) I nowhere confirmed that I made a rant. As I commented you afterwards, I just "repeated" your blaming me of rant in an humor `...yeah, I say rant (while I just stand for the top-class secure-apps),  and you are all totally correct (while being on opposite side of all top-class apps)...`  this was a expression of my comment, and not a my confirmation of a rant.
3) Again, please cite from my Answer where I express opinions without an argument, and why my answer doesn't have a right

Comment: Lastly, as I was unable to cooperate with your impregnable thought about the subject (which I consider as not an ideal/accurate in security field), and instead of help to correct my q/a (to fit here), you are still emphasizing on my somewhere found misbehaviors.
That's why  I had to ask for another moderator to look into subject (because otherwise there is no point -  I am appealing the case with same person with whom I already appealed). That's why I wanted other mods to look into this, who might agree and allow the topic to be left opened, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Your question is ill-formed, has two completely different questions, and when I asked for the *question* to be clarified, you replied with "I've expanded that matter in my answer below, hope that makes the arguments I wanted to say." All of this, all of your comments, everything, points to the fact that what you wanted to do was to post an answer. The question was merely a prompt to make the post you wanted. Your question, as phrased, is unanswerable by anyone else since someone else would have to share your perspective on "really secure apps".

Comment: Do you want a better question? What about "why do 2FA apps on mobile devices not have locks?" And we have some answers around different aspects of that: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184452/why-do-many-totp-devices-or-tfa-apps-use-none-or-simple-access-password and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246158/is-it-safe-to-use-2fa-within-a-password-manager-relative-to-using-a-separate-app and

Comment: I don't think you are driving into correct direction. This is how you see the subject, but I am not you, and I had different question. I've given reasonable examples which you till moment avoided to respond, namely, the Top apps out there, who has all my mentioned lock-mechanisms, and my question  (formed [like this laconic](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/i-want-to-appeal-deletion-of-a-specific-question/3463?noredirect=1#comment8739_3462)) is quite legit, to ask , that some apps do this and some app do that , and which is safer? The obvious fact (which

Comment: you made a joke of me, saying that I was congratulating myself for that answer) is that the apps that offer lock-mechanisms are obviously safer, but you insist (ed) that there is no need of safety on device for such apps, which is a huge mistake and non-secure advise imho. I also named arguments and examples, while such non-protection is equal to unsafety. However, you just have personal thought about subject, opposite to me, and thereafter, for some very unimportant second-hand reason ('rant'), you deleted my q/a (even if it was not good, you had to allow it for downvotes to see,but..).

Comment: (fun fact - if question/answer was deleted according to what I declare & admit [as after you thought that I admitted it as "rant", you deleted them] then I declare and admit that it was not a rant, and while I said about that, I did ironically say about it being a rant. However, if you wanted to react according my writing, that this is what I write - it was not a rant, and moreover adjusted q/a as best as I could to fit SE). best luck.

Comment: You are concluding that I removed the question because I do not like your answer or arguments. Please remove this from your thinking. The question you asked and the content of your answer are completely different issues. Your question was, and still is, unanswerable. Your current version is purely opinion-based. "What makes something highly secure?" is not answerable. You need to explain the threat model in order to ask what controls can counter those threats. This goes back to my very first comment: "As always, "really secure" against what threats?"

Comment: and "You appear to have some underlying assumptions and standards that need to be explained."

Comment: Schroeder, when I explained that in question, you say that I express opinion in question. I really don't understand what to do. 
In previous edit, I had these addition in the end "(i.e. having passcode or not having it, having fingerprint or not having...) I've tried to detail that in question, but you rejected that too. It's surprising you are saying that it's opinion based. If so, then everything, even a security is relative (Why leaving bank-account open in an pc is unsecure? maybe no one will enter and steal anything? ) However, question I asked about apps is some bit deterministic

Comment: You have not understood. Your question is asking for opinions because people have to make a guess about what "highly secure" means to them in different contexts. Threat models make it specific.

Comment: and after all of this time spent in dispute, couldn't you advised me two sentences to help to make & write down it as needed? As you see, I was unable to make it as you think.  Couldn't you help to edit the Question (as you clearly see what I am trying to ask), and per my answer (which I initially intended to post an answer to my QA, as StackExchange gives that option to person to answer his question even under question form), you could have helped to end this dispute, by editing the question to make it fit as you think (and I would have said thanks for that, and also for editing answer)

Comment: No, I couldn't. Because, I said, very, very clearly, *I do not know what you want to ask* (you had 2 very different questions rolled into one) *and your question seemed to be a prompt for the answer you wanted to give*. I still have no idea what your good-faith question is. You want to tell us something, not ask us something. Only ***you*** know the threat scenarios that matter to you. So, don't put any of this on me as my responsibility. This is ***your*** question that you want to ask (if, in fact, you actually have a question).

Comment: Ok, is current (last edit I made a few seconds ago) a bit more clear what I want to ask?  Also, you allowed me to post an answer and even edited that (you didn't delete that outright), and I said thanks for that. I thought that answer was allowed to exist. Why you deleted then?  

`..You are concluding that I removed the question because I do not like your answer or arguments. ..`  yes, that is conclusion, because you allowed q/a in the beggining and didnt delete ( and I was glad you allowed them), but after I commented a specific comment later, then things gone wild.

Comment: Did you have a chance to reply to the above last comment? I was referring the last update of question, if that was reworded to be more specific.